# Acer A515-43 can't install UEFI (USB)

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, acer, aspire

This A515-43 is SSD and UEFI only. I prefer Ubuntu. However I've tried numerous distributions. All on USB created with rufus. They all fail to boot similarly. 'Problem loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate'. I've searched and searched for a work around. I've tried everything imaginable: I've disabled fastboot (bios and windows), tried booting with secure boot disabled (and enabled using a trusted boot efi file), I've shutdown windows from command line to get around 'unclean file system' error, I've downgraded bios and upgraded bios. But nothing gets me any closer to booting. The closest I've seem to come was with the Debian installer (ncurses I think).

But I did not want to go through with install before I could boot and run in live mode to make sure that the laptop will work once Linux successfully boots. Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can get Ubuntu to boot and install on this laptop? I really dislike using Windows and I seem to be stuck using it right now. The one thing that I haven't been able to pursue is modifying GRUB. I don't have a working Linux system to update GRUB.

Comment: Perhaps some info here? Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702 Acer Aspire A515-54G Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detected

Comment: TY for replying. I've attempted all of that before (minus windows safe mode). I followed it to a 'T' again (safe mode in windows) but still same result. This laptop only has the option of AHCI in the bios. So that was already set.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware?

Comment: I assume UEFI is updated via BIOS and I currently have BIOS on the latest version available (I've tried others). I am currently updating chipset drivers. I'll let you know if that makes any difference (providing that my machine will still boot when I'm done lol)

Comment: Good news/Bad news. Good News: I now have a fully updated Windows system. Bad news: Linux still won't boot.

Comment: Some vendors still call UEFI as BIOS, but it is emulation. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since release of Windows 8 in 2012. Post link in question: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: TY for your input. I don't think you need to worry about me going too far with it though haha. I downloaded the tool and created a bootable USB. Secure Boot and Fast Boot turned off in the BIOS. It would not boot in normal mode. I received the same message as distro install ISO's - 'Problem loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate'. Failsafe mode gave me verbose output which ended with 'kernel panic - not syncing...'

Comment: More info - FreeBSD boots. It sure seems like a Linux Kernel issue (or something else causing the kernel to panic). Further - all linux distro's show up as Linpus Lite at the initial boot selection screen. FreeBSD (USB created from .img file) showed up as 'SanDisk USB'.

Comment: Check that last post. FreeBSD booted to a command prompt OK. I tried GhostBSD (ability to use live with GUI) and it failed during boot as well.

Comment: Does FreeBSD use Secure Boot as the X509 issue is normally related to having that on. Or missing file in /EFI/Boot or /EFI/ubuntu. Do you have mmx64.efi in those folders?

Comment: secure boot was disabled every time I attempted to install or load a USB iso. Yes I checked the EFI folders (when I added trusted boot files) and mmx64.efi was there.

Comment: This says something about changing setup mode? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218700/integrity-problem-loading-x-509-certificate-65  and setting trust on grub in flash drive? https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/535157/error-trying-to-install-ubuntu-in-aspire-a51

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (sort of). I was never able to completely boot live from USB. Although I now have Linux installed on the internal HDD (I still have windows on the SSD). Once I got the HDD installed, I had an extra drive. So I was able to experiment with the installation process without worrying about rendering my entire system unusable. I was able to install via NetInstall (mini.iso). I found that my usb drive was becoming unresponsive during the boot process. One time when it became unresponsive, I simply unplugged it and plugged it back in. The system recognized my usb drive once again and the installation process continued. It might have worked the same for a normal install. But I was already trying the NetInstall at that point.