# Help with understanding log

Tags: log

just installed Ubuntu 20.04.
the system keeps freezing and i have to turn it off with the power button and on again.
Can someone help me analyze this log file, if there's maybe something wrong that i'm unaware of?

```
11:42:46 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
11:42:45 logger: /usr/sbin/vmware-authdlauncher: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
11:42:37 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.6: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x0143a000
11:42:35 systemd: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:amdgpu_bl0.
11:42:35 systemd-backlig: amdgpu_bl0: Failed to write system 'brightness' attribute: No such device or address
11:42:35 systemd: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
11:42:35 systemd: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
11:42:35 systemd-backlig: Failed to get backlight or LED device 'backlight:acpi_video0': No such device
11:42:34 kernel: snd_pci_acp3x 0000:03:00.5: Invalid ACP audio mode : 1
11:42:33 kernel: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator failed with exit status 1.
11:42:33 kernel: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/swapfile.swap, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?
11:42:33 kernel: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/swapfile.swap, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?
11:42:33 kernel: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/swapfile.swap, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?
11:42:33 kernel: integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
```

ar@Aruntu:~$ sudo lshw -C memory
[sudo] password for ar:

```
  *-memory                  
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 1
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 12GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: Row of chips DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: 8ATF1G64HZ-2G3B1
          vendor: Micron Technology
          physical id: 0
          serial: 14D7D62B
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: 4ATF51264HZ-2G6E1
          vendor: Micron Technology
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 3
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 192KiB
       capacity: 192KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 4
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: d
       version: E8CN25WW
       date: 10/13/2020
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
```

ar@Aruntu:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
E8CN25WW
ar@Aruntu:~$ free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          9.7Gi       2.0Gi       2.4Gi       122Mi       5.3Gi       7.3Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi        14Mi       2.0Gi
```

ar@Aruntu:~$ cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=0cf09152-a222-487d-a43e-6d12f148d8bc /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=B346-574B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

ar@Aruntu:~$

Comment: Have you [tested the storage device](https://askubuntu.com/a/1226389/1222991) to see if there are issues?

Comment: i will try this and post the resuls.
Thanks!

Comment: when i enter the command i get:
ar@Aruntu:~$ sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sdb 
badblocks: No such file or directory while trying to determine device size

Comment: Do NOT use `badblocks` directly. Very bad. Use `e2fsck -fccky`, or a variation thereof.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @matigo Do NOT recommend using `badblocks`. See `man badblocks` and you'll find "For this reason,
       it  is  strongly recommended that users not run badblocks directly, but
       rather use the -c option of the e2fsck and mke2fs programs."

Comment: @heynnema thanks, please see the question for information you requested.

Comment: Also, DON'T bad block a SSD or nvme.

Comment: @heynnema , i added the information in my question please check.
i have not enabled zswap.

Comment: @ArsenioRechards Everything looks good there now. Do you have a Ryzen processor? If so, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: @ArsenioRechards Status please...

Comment: @heynnema ,i just downloaded, i'm gonna try it
i have a Lenovo V14 with a AMD Athlon Gold 3150U with Radeon graphics.
12GB DDR4, 512GB Nvme ssd

Comment: @ArsenioRechards Status please...

Comment: @heynnema, all 4 passed!i think i'm gonna try reinstalling 20.04.
format and start from scratch, thanks for your support.

Comment: @ArsenioRechards Good luck! Please do keep me posted.

Comment: @heynnema, yes I will.
Thank you once more for your support, i appreciate it.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema, i just did the reinstall but it already froze once.not during install.
i think maybe this laptop model has some issues, it's a brand new machine.
it really happens randomly.I'm a bit sad because i really want to switch to Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you ever do the `memtest` that I requested? Also show me `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: And also tell me the EXACT model # of the laptop... V14-xxx.

Comment: And `free -h` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @heynnema Lenovo V14-ADA, i added 8G memory and 512nvme.
i did do the memtest and passed all of them,there was a html report but i don't where it was saved.please see info in question

Comment: Good on `memtest`. Thanks. Show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: @heynnema, Noted. I increased the swapfile successfully,however to update the bios i need the windows platform, i tried updating from a windows vm but that doesn't work.
so this means i'll have to install windows on this laptop in order to update the BIOS.

Comment: @heynnema, I just updated BIOS.
let's monitor and see what it does

Comment: Please keep me posted

Comment: @heynnema,No success it just kept freezing more and more.
i switched to Fedora 34, and guess what!the same thing happens.
i'm unable to work so i think i'm gonna switch back to windows for now, i will try linux when i have different hardware,thanks for your support!

Comment: Sorry we couldn't get it going reliably for you :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your /etc/fstab is incorrect.

It shows three entries for /swapfile...

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

Edit your /etc/fstab using the `terminal` application, with the command `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`, and remove the first two /swapfile lines, and leave the third /swapfile line, save the edited file, and then reboot.

**Extra note**: Don't use `badblocks` or `e2fsck` to bad block a SSD/nvme.

**Update #1:**

**BIOS**

Lenovo V14-ADA

You have version E8CN25WW, dated 10/13/2020. There's a newer BIOS available, version E8CN27WW, dated 05 Feb 2021, and can be downloaded [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v14-ada/downloads/DS543481).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**SWAP**

Your 2G /swapfile is too small. We'll increase it to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 12G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #2:**

This computer freezes with Ubuntu and Fedora 34. Switching back to Windows for now.

Comment: Hi, i'm new to this so can you please be more specific?
what do you mean by "remove the first two lines"?
how do i remove the lines?

Comment: @ArsenioRechards I updated my answer for you.

Comment: @heynema, thank you for your support.
i did the commands i will monitor the system for a day or two, if it doesn't happen again i will sure mark this answer as correct.

Comment: @heynema, Hi it just happened again while i was running a VM
it also happens randomly even with no VM running.
do you see any other thing in the log that might cause this?

Comment: Show me the `cat /etc/fstab` again, and upload /var/log/syslog to paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL and I'll take a look for you. Ping me when it's done.

Comment: i added the cat /etc/fstab to my question please check,
for some reason i'm not able to post the log,i get an error bad gateway after i click paste
can i share it with you another way?

Comment: @ArsenioRechards Your /etc/fstab is still showing 3 /swapfile lines. I thought that you had edited that. At paste.ubuntu.com you tried to paste your clipboard that contained the output of `cat /var/log/syslog`, yes?

Comment: ,see url for pasted data https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/m7q8dyNJVX/
i removed the lines correctly

Comment: i also added another log please check, i only added the part where the machine froze, between 8.48 & 9:13, do see something that might cause the freeze?

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XgtZbZT4zk/

Comment: @ArsenioRechards I'm still seeing "Jun  6 08:12:08 Aruntu kernel: [    2.672474] systemd-fstab-generator[236]: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/swapfile.swap, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?" in syslog. Based on the last `cat /etc/fstab` that you showed me, it doesn't look like you removed the extra /swapfile lines. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ArsenioRechards Have you installed/enabled zswap?

Comment: @ArsenioRechards What video card? What version driver? Show me `sudo lshw -C video`.

Comment: @ArsenioRechards Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.