# Windows bootloader error: thread exception not handled (dual booted laptop)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, windows, bootloader

### The problem

I'm new to ubuntu and linux in general (aside from android). I dual booted my laptop that was originaly windows 10. The laptop has grub and windows bootloaders that I use for booting ubuntu or windows respectively. Windows works fine and can be booted normaly, until I boot into ubuntu. When I boot into ubuntu, something screws with windows up. If I turn off ubuntu and try to boot back into windows, I get stuck in a loop: the windows bootloader outputs error:

> "thread exception not handled"

or it just tries to "fix" my pc. Then when it either reboots or it turns off (and I start it again), one of these are happening again - either the error or the fix pc thing and I get stuck in a loop. This happens for few minutes until the problem seemingly fixes itself, and I can boot into windows. The problem doesn't happen anymore, until I try to boot into ubuntu. The same problem then happens again and again...
Is there a way to fix this without the windows bootloader problem?
I'd like to switch between ubuntu and windows just by turning my laptop off and booting into the other OS, without having to wait for minutes until windows bootloader fixes itself.

### laptop stats:

- acer swift 3
- 512 GB SSD
- AMD Ryzen 5500u

### Few notes:

- I tried searching few tutorials to fix the loop but none of them
  accounted for dual boot
- The windows terminal isn't accessible in the fix pc menu since my password doesn't work until the problem resolves itself

### Update

After booting Boot-repair my ubuntu partition reseted to clean instal, I'm left with: Linpus lite, Windows Boot Manager, ubuntu, (another) linpus lite bootloaders (USB), windows partition unaffected

Comment: Is booting Windows from grub the issue or booting directly from UEFI? Windows updates reset some UEFI settings, so recheck all those you originally changed. What versions of Ubuntu and Windows? Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware to latest available? To see your configuration: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: 1. I boot windows via windows bootloader, I tried loading the bootloader via grub or uefi but the result is same. 2. I have the latest BIOS/UEFI, I believe I have a recent SSD firmware also since my laptop is also quite recent (I can't really check because the Kingston SSD manager somehow doesn't detect it). 3. I use windows home 21h2 and ubuntu 20.04 lts. 4. I'm not sure what Bootinfo are you talking about.

Comment: Is it an SSD or NVMe SSD? Click on link above to download Boot-Repair and only run its report and upload to the pastebin site, so we can review it.

Comment: I have an M2 SSD, I tried running the tool you linked, but when I did it, it printed "problem loading x.509 certificate and a couple of errors following, It didn't ask anything just reseted my ubuntu back to what can be considered a clean install, it also added new bootloaders...

Comment: the other bootloader added is just the USB

Comment: Should I try clearing the ubuntu partitions and bootloaders starting anew?

Comment: On x509 error: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218700/integrity-problem-loading-x-509-certificate-65