# integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65 on dual boot, but it continues booting up normally

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm new to using Ubuntu or linux in general and dual booting. Currently using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
I encounter the error

> integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65

every time I boot Ubuntu from the GRUB menu and it finished booting up without crashes or anything breaking when I use Ubuntu.
What I tried is disabling secure boot from my BIOS, and checking for bad sectors on my SSD showed no errors.
Do I just ignore the error since Ubuntu boots up fine?

Comment: There is no such version as called latest. What if someone reads this a year form now. A full version is required. First this has nothing to do with the hard drive. Yes if everything works you can ignore it but you may want to find out what it is. When I google this error it tells me that you may have changed the kernel? What kernel are you running?

Comment: @David Noted. I specified my Ubuntu version. My Linux kernel is 5.15.0-50-generic

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same problem (although this machine is not dual boot): at startup, the message

> integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65

is printed (twice), but boot then continues without further problems. Currently investigating.

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on Acer Aspire E15 laptop.

**Update**: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218700/integrity-problem-loading-x-509-certificate-65) suggests the problem is an obsolete X.509 certificate in the BIOS of some Acer laptops.