# ntegrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65 message on startup on ubuntu acer nitro 5

Tags: 22.04, acer

I am getting this message during startup of my acer nitro 5 laptop.

***[    3.173272] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
[    3.173311] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
in ubuntu 22 in acer nitro5***

What does it mean?How to fix this issue?Is this harmful or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218700/integrity-problem-loading-x-509-certificate-65)

Comment: this solution doesnot work for me