# I get these everytime I boot into ubuntu, along with this it i have to always forget then re-pair with every bluetooth device

Tags: boot, dual-boot

- integrity : problem loading x.509 certification -65
- integrity : problem loading x.509 certification -65
- /devnvme0n1p5: clean, 4333973/4481024 files, 4971737/17920256 blocks
- iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT : invalid buffer designation
- iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT : invalid buffer designation
- Bluetooth: hci0 : Malformed MSFT vendor event : 0x02

Please Keep in mind that I'm writing this from a image i took of my laptop while it was booting, since then i have upgraded my Ubuntu to 23.10 ( it was jammy jellyfish before ), my grub version of upon using " grub-install --version " is :- (GRUB) 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4,kernel is:- 6.5.0-25-generic  , my system is a Ubuntu with kde plasma standard install along with its default gnome de, it is with a dual boot with windows 11 on my acer laptop.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218700/integrity-problem-loading-x-509-certificate-65 is the same and has things to try.